# Most efficent way to select a collection of objects from DbContext

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

In MVC if I need to get one object from the database using the primary key I can use the find function:

```
public static Element List(Guid id)
{
    DBContext db = new DBContext();
    return db.Elements.Find(id);
}
```

What is the most efficient way to get a collection of objects?

This does not seem very efficient, altough it will work:

```
public static IEnumerable<Element> List(IEnumerable<Guid> ids)
{
    foreach (Guid id in ids)
        yield return Get(id);
}
```

Presumably each call of Get is one database request.

Is there a function like Find that I can just hand a collection of primary keys and get a collection back? I don't see one, what's the best way to write one?

Comment: How many elements can `ids` contain?

Comment: I wouldn't expect more than a few dozen, though more often that not it will be single figures.

Answer (score 2):

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();
List<Guid> ids = ....

return db.Elements.Where(z => ids.Contains(z.Id));  // Use .ToList() to materialize entities
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to use Linq:

```
List<Guid> your_ids = ..... ;

using(DBContext db = new DBcontext())
{
   var lst = from e in db.Elements 
             where your_ids.Contains(e.Id) 
             select e;

   List<Guid> result_list = lst.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the best performance you should turn off change tracking (makes a huge difference)
(copied code from ken2k)

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();
List<Guid> ids = ....

return db.Elements
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(z => ids.Contains(z.Id));  // Use .ToList() to materialize entities
```